# How to serve a backend server which is local to the angular frontend?

Tags: angular

I have an angular app running on an apache server at `http://localhost`.
I have a backend flask server running on the same machine on port 5200 (`http://localhost:5200`).

I can access the backend through the frontend from the server, but when I try from another machine, the front-end obviously refers the client to his own machine which isn't running the backend.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {    

  dataUrl = 'http://localhost:5002/api'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData(): Observable<DataItem> {    
    return this.http.get<DataItem>(this.dataUrl)
  }
}
```

Is there a way for me to do something like this?

```
dataUrl = 'http://${SameIpAsFrontEnd}:5002/api'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these purposes, there are the environment files. You can use them to refer to different backend servers, which are in your case `localhost` and ´`. You can use the standard development and prod environment file or you can create your own ones. 
If you use`ng serve` it will automatically run in dev mode, which will provide the dev environment file. But you can also provide an arbitrary file with (for example):

```
ng serve -e prod
```

Environment files are located in the directory `environments`. Suppose the file looks like this:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    server: "localhost"
};
```

you can access the base URL with `environment.server` in your REST service for example. 
In the standard angular project, there will be `environment.prod.ts` and `environment.ts`. `ng serve` without `-e` will take `environment.ts`. If you use `-e prod` it will take the other one. Of course, you can also define an environment file like this: `environment.stub.ts` (`ng serve -e stub`).

In your example you can use:

```
dataUrl = 'http://' + environment.server + ':5002/api'
```

To build your application with a specific env file use:

```
ng build --prod --env=prod
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help,

Try hosting site on first machine using command: 
    `ng serve --host 192.168.1.xx --port 80`
Then enter the IP and port in the browser from another machine on same network: 
    `192.168.1.xx:80`

Comment: That allows me to access the front-end from the LAN, but doesn't help me to find the back-end which is not served with ng.